# Trying to query AD on a linked server error message is 7321

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Trying to query AD on a linked server error message is 7321 error occurred while preparing the query.  Any suggestions?

```
Select Name, EmployeeID, Mail, SamAccountName
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, 'SELECT Name, EmployeeID, Mail
FROM ''LDAP://DC=mydomain,DC=com''
WHERE  objectClass=''user'' AND EmployeeID > 0 and SamAccountName = ''f.bower''')
```

Comment: I think the `LDAP://DC=mydomain,DC=com` thing must be enclosed double quotes rather than *doubled single* quotes, i.e. like this: `FROM "LDAP://DC=mydomain,DC=com"`.

Answer (score 4):

At a minimum, in the outer query you want `SamAccountName` which you are using within the openquery as a filter but do not have in your select list there.

Whether that's the root issue or just a byproduct of you doctoring this up for the site remains to be seen.

```
Select Name, EmployeeID, Mail, SamAccountName
FROM OPENQUERY(ADSI, 'SELECT Name, EmployeeID, Mail, SamAccountName
FROM ''LDAP://DC=mydomain,DC=com''
WHERE  objectClass=''user'' AND EmployeeID > 0 and SamAccountName = ''f.bower''')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have a handy `ADSI` linked server on my test system, I used `OPENROWSET` to test the query itself, which after adding the `samAccountName` column to the LDAP query results, as recommended by @billinkc in his answer, seems to work.

```
SELECT Name
    , EmployeeID
    , Mail
    , samAccountName
FROM OPENROWSET('ADSDSOObject'
    , 'adsdatasource'
    , 'SELECT Name, EmployeeID, Mail, samAccountName
       FROM ''LDAP://DC=mydomain,DC=com''
       WHERE objectClass=''user'' 
           AND EmployeeID > 0 
           AND samAccountName = ''myusername'''
    ) ds;
```

Perhaps there is an issue with your linked server?